# Determine the interval for convergence

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, analysis, numerical-methods

Textbook problem from Numerical Analysis course.

> Consider the matrix $A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}{0.9} & {-0.2} & {-0.2} \\ {0.1} & {0.7} & {-e} \\ {0.1} & {-0.3} & {0.5}\end{array}\right)$ Determine the interval $J$ such that the Neumann Series applied to some matrix $B$ converges to the inverse of $A$ when $e \in J$

My idea is that since the Neumann Series only converges whenever $||A|| < 1$ I would simply write out the norm of $A$ with the unknown $e$ and isolate for $e$, and thus figure out what the interval $J$ is. I am unsure as to wheter this approach is correct or if i am missing something, and there is some trick i can use? I cant seem to find any examples of this in the book (www.ma.utexas.edu/CNA/NA3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that a Neumann series $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty B^n$$ converges to $(I-B)^{-1}$ provided $\|B\|<1$ (you can actually do better via Gelfand's formula). The typical norm that is used is the operator norm induced by the $2$-norm: $$\|B\|=\sqrt{\max_{\lambda\in\sigma(B^*B)}\lambda}.$$

If you want to find a Neumann series converges to the inverse of $A$, then note that $$A^{-1}=(I-(I-A))^{-1}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (I-A)^n,$$ where now we require that $$\|I-A\|<1.$$ So, the matrix you need to consider is $B=I-A,$ not just $A$.